# How to kill TCP/TCP6 of vncserver without ~:1.pid, ~:2.pid files ? and How to uninstall vnc related files clealry?

Tags: server, vnc

I have a big problem to set up vncserver to my lab server computer.

1. I am newbie to set up `vncserver`. To set up `vncserver`, first, I followed up someone's guide which use `vnc4server`. It worked, but terminal window only appeared when I connected to server computer from my desktop by using `VNCviewer`. so I tried to solve the problem, but I failed. From this moment, big problem has occurred. I deleted `.vnc` folder, `vnc4server` package without kill vncserver using `vncserver -kill :1`. Because the `:01.pid` file is deleted, I couldn't kill vncserver. When I tried to kill vncserver without `.pid` file, the Error:

   ```
   Can't find file /root/.vnc/node03:1.pid
   You'll have to kill the Xtightvnc process manually
   ```

   Currently, vncserver `:1` and `:2` is not deleted. :(
   I want to kill them and start setting up vncserver again.
   Please give me comments.
2. How to remove vnc related files and folders clearly? Cause I will re-try to set up vncserver on server computer after solving problem 1.

Thank you for your solution in advance.